# Specialized Hardrock rear hanger

Tags: mountain-bike, derailleur

I just fixed my first puncture on a recently bought Hardrock (Evans)and discovered that the rear hanger is not attached to the frame.  This made refitting the wheel a bit of a struggle.

There is a hole through locating stud so should it have a bolt going through it?

Cheers

Comment: It is not a bolt but specific derailleur hanger hardware. It was probable loose and fell off. Your LBS should be able to supply you with a new one.

Comment: You'll need a Specialized dealer to order this part, most likely. The **[derailer](http://www.sheldonbrown.com/derailer.html)** hangar I ordered for my Stumpjumper was very inexpensive. :)

Answer (score 1):

If the hanger is still attached, there are two possible attachment options:

1. The most common - a chainring bolt
2. Two smaller bolts, often counter-sunk (I can't recall exactly, but it's not important)

With either option, it's still a standard part, something your LBS should have on hand.

Also, if the bike was purchased recently, the bolt that fell off the hanger is *not* caused due to an issue you caused, and should be covered for free (at the very least the labor should be covered).